# fs.open(path, 'r', function(fd, err) err returns 12

Tags: node.js

I am using fs.open to check for the existence of a file,

```
module.exports.build.module = function(args) {
        var path = modulesPath + args[0] + '/blueprint.js';
        console.log(path);

        fs.open(path, 'r', function(fd, err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(fd);
        });
    }
```

It seems when the file path is correct, I get err is equal to 12. When I provide an invalid path I get (as expected) " [Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/Will/dev/000/lib/builders../../modules/comments/blueprint.js']". I can't find what this err code means online so I thought I'd come here? I also recall it saying "11" at some point , but not sure what the conditions were that brought that about.

I should also mention that **fd is null.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) says, the correct signature for the callback is `(err, fd)`.  You'll find that the "err" you're getting of `11` or `12` is a valid file descriptor.

In general, callbacks take an error as the first argument in node.